# Java - How do I find the length of a string in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, alphabetical, string-length

All I need to know is how to find the length of the string inside of the array.  I also would like to know how to find which string comes first in alphabetical order in the array.

Comment: this is really 2 questions. Both of which probably already have answers here on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945656/list-an-array-of-strings-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: @peter I think he's having problems writing a proper question :/

Comment: @Bohemian Your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 5):

`myArr[0].length()`

This will access the string at location 0, then get the length of it.

Also, for sorting alphabetically, you can use

`Arrays.sort(myArr);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.length` method on any string array element to get its length,
And to sort that array alphabetically you ca use `.sort` method -

For example -

```
String[] strings = { "Hello ", "This ", "is", "Sorting", "Example" };
Arrays.sort(strings);
```

So after sorting `strings[0]` would be `Example` and `string[0].length()` would be `7`

Comment: You mean `string[0].length()`, right?