# Ruby Control Flow = (equals) and if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, equals

I am a real Newb when it comes to Ruby, but I have been learning it using the code academy website. I started going outside the guidelines for the specific task I was supposed to be doing, only to my surprise I got an error when typing the following code:

```
print "please type in an integer for x:"
x = gets.to_i

print "please type in an integer for y:"
y = gets.to_i

if "x" < "y"
    puts "#{x} is less than #{y}"
elsif "x" > "y"
    puts "#{x} is greater than #{y}"
else
    puts "#{x} is equal to #{y}"
end
```

It is a really simple code but the end result is supposed to do this:

```
"x" < "y" will report "x is less than y"
"x" > "y" will report "x is greater than y"
"x" = "y" will report "x is equal to y"
```

both the smaller and greater work, but it cannot calculate if x and y are the same, instead just reporting "x is lees than y"

I'm not sure if it's a bug with the Code Academy website, or if it's something I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to put quotes around variable names in the if clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as below :

```
if x < y
    puts "#{x} is less than #{y}"
elsif x > y
    puts "#{x} is greater than #{y}"
else
    puts "#{x} is equal to #{y}"
end
```

`"x"` create a new string and not treated as the number you took from the console. But when you are write `"#{x}"`, it is giving the number, but in string format using *interpolation*.

When you would write `"x" > "y"`, you are checking/testing those string literals 'x' and 'y' by their [*lexicographical ordering*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810619/how-to-explain-sorting-numerical-lexicographical-and-collation-with-examples), but `x > y` is the comparisons of the two numbers you took from the console using `gets.to_i`.

Comment: Ahh, thank yo very much. I knew I was doing something as senile as forgetting the basic rules of Ruby. I applaud you, good sir. And I will also delete this question as it was a silly mistake.

Comment: alright sorry. I wish I was better at online forums like this one but unfortunately I don't take things like this as seriously as some other people. and yes I am talking about you.

Comment: @LewisHarris What do you mean by *yes I am talking about you* ?