# Delphi: How to compare strings by their lexicographical order (dictionary order)?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, fpc

The standards Delphi RTL string comparison routines compare strings by ASCII ordering.

As far as I concern, lexicographic ordering is based only on the letters of the alphabet; **it is the ordering system used in dictionaries**.

Is there a Delphi native function to compare strings by lexicographical order? For now, I don't need a complex solution to support alphabets other than English.

### UPDATE

I don't know the detail rule about lexicographical ordering system, but I know one of the rule, that is, this ordering system will treat for example, **a-b** is greater than **aa**. However, it was based on my observation on the English dictionaries in my hand. Perhaps, there are still rules that I'm not concerned.

Comment: So, is this a Delphi (ANSI or Unicode ?) or FPC (ANSI) question ? You're talking about Delphi all the time but finally used FPC tags. Also, which platforms do you target (there is a set of functions for what you need in MSVCRT, but you'd need to target Windows) ?

Comment: It is not matter whether it's Delphi or FPC, Ansi, Unicode, or UTF,  because I just want to look into code implementation, then modify it to suite my need. I'm talking about English alphabets, not alphabets in other languages.

Comment: You were talking about native functions, so MSVCRT's [`*coll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7cwbx4t.aspx) functions were the first I've hit. But those you can use only on Windows platform.

Comment: English alphabet have no collation issues, and lexicographical string ordering is the same as case-insensitive ordering; the `AnsiCompareText` function is doing case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Do you mean you want your comparison function to return that `'a'` < `'123456789 b'` < `'c'` because the characters before the `'b'` aren't letters? If not, can you edit your question to give some concrete examples of how Delphi's own RTL functions don't meet your needs?

Comment: For simple definitions [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810619/how-to-explain-sorting-numerical-lexicographical-and-collation-with-examples)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. ASCII only has English letters anyway. Did you really mean ASCII? What's more, the English letters appear in ASCII in alphabetical order. I think you need to step back and work out what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I don't know the detail rule about lexicographical ordering system, but I know one of the rule, that is, this ordering system will treat for example, <b>a-b</b> is greater than <b>aa</b>. However, it is based on my observation on the English dictionaries in my hand. Perhaps, there is still rule that I'm not concerned. That is why I ask about it here.

Answer (score 3):

The `AnsiCompareText` function is doing case-insensitive string comparison taking the collation order of the system locale into account.

Just to be sure I've run the following test on a system with 1251 codepage:

```
procedure Test;
var
  S1, S2: string;

begin
  S1:= 'им';
  S2:= 'ём';
  Writeln(IntToHex(Integer(S1[1]), 4));    // 0438
  Writeln(IntToHex(Integer(S2[1]), 4));    // 0451
  Writeln(AnsiCompareText(S1, S2));        // 1 (means S1 > S2)
end;
```

You can see that the letter 'и' has the code (0x0438) less than the letter 'ё' (0x0451) but in Russian alphabet 'ё' precedes 'и', and `AnsiCompareText` function compares 'ё' and 'и' according to the rules of Russian alphabet, not according to the numeric values of their codes.